# How to specify random effects in lme?

Tags: r, mixed-model, cross-validation, biostatistics

I have searched for this online for hours but none of online posts is what I am looking for. My question is very easy to implement in SAS Proc mixed procedure but I am not sure how to do it in lme and/or lmer packages. Assume, I have a model,
$y = \mu + \alpha + \beta +\alpha\beta + e$, 
where $\alpha$ is fixed but $\beta$ and $\alpha\beta$ are random. My R code is

```
 f1 = lme(y ~ factor(a), data = mydata,
     random = list(factor(b) = ~ 1, factor(a):factor(b) = ~ 1))
```

Error: unexpected `=` in:

```
 f1 = lme(y ~ factor(a), data = mydata,
          random = list(factor(a) =
```

Could someone please tell me how to specify these random effects in lme?
many thanks in advance

Comment: It helps to use `dput` to get the code needed to recreate your data.  From the comment you left, the result is `structure(list(method = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
day = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
level = c(142.3, 144, 134.9, 146.3, 148.6, 156.5, 152, 151.4, 
142.9, 147.4, 125.9, 127.6, 135.5, 138.9, 142.9, 142.3)), .Names = c("method", 
"day", "level"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: it's a really old post but if someone else like me end up here he/she might like this one too
https://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer#power-analysis-and-simulating-these-models

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this, it's a standard way to do a split plot.  The notation `/` means that method is nested in day.

```
lme(level~method, random=~1|day/method, data=d)
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thank you very much. Your R output is exactly the same with SAS output and the textbook. But Why we have to use "nested" in R syntax. Because in the textbook, it clearly states that $\alpha\beta$ is an random interaction term and I also use random interaction term in SAS. Could you please tell me why/how to specify an random interaction effect in lme, if it is possible? many many thanks Tu.2

Comment: Your question isn't about R syntax, it's about what nesting means.  Nesting B in A (with A/B) creates two variables, A and the interaction between A and B, which is exactly what you describe.

Comment: Hi, This is a great explanation. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

It would help a lot if you provided a data.frame. Now it is not clear what is a grouping factor. I judge that it is $\beta$. Then in `lme` notation your model should be written as follows:

```
lme(y~a,random=~a|b, data=mydata)
```

Comment: Hi mpiktas, thank you for your response but the R result is very different from SAS proc mixed procedure. The SAS output is the same with the answer in a textbook(Kuehk RO. 1999. Design of experiments: statistical principles of research design and analysis, 2nd edition). The dataset is        method day level
1   1 142.3
1   1 144.0
1   2 134.9
1   2 146.3
1   3 148.6
1   3 156.5
1   4 152.0
1   4 151.4
2   1 142.9
2   1 147.4
2   2 125.9
2   2 127.6
2   3 135.5
2   3 138.9
2   4 142.9
2   4 142.3