# Is there a way to specify a lme model with more than one within-subjects factor?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

### The data

Suppose we have a dataset `d` with two between-subject factors (i.e., groups), `group` and `condition`, and two within-subject factors (i.e., repeated-measures factors), `topic` and `problem` (I uploaded the data to pastebin, so everybody should be able to obtain it):

```
> d <- read.table(url("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4hRFyaRj"), colClasses = c(rep("factor", 6), "numeric"))
> str(d)
'data.frame':   2928 obs. of  6 variables:
  $ code     : Factor w/ 183 levels "A03U","A08C",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  $ group    : Factor w/ 2 levels "control","experimental": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  $ condition: Factor w/ 3 levels "alternatives",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
  $ topic    : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
  $ problem  : Factor w/ 4 levels "AC","DA","MP",..: 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 ...
  $ mean     : num  94.5 94.5 86.5 84.5 80 46.5 73.5 43.5 51 39 ...
```

The data is from a behavioral experiment in which participants in six groups (2 levels of `group` times 3 levels of `condition`) worked on 16 tasks (for each of 4 `topics` 4 different `problems`). Allocation of participants to group/condition was fully random. Presentation of tasks was random insofar that problem was blocked within topic (i.e., for each topic all problems where presented sequentially), but order of problem and topic was random.
**Update:** The factor identifying the participant (in which topic and problem are nested) is `code`.

### The Problem

How can I fit this dataset using `lme`?
(Sidenote: I would also consider using `lme4`, but I am kind of afraid of not having p-values, if there is something easily digestible as p-values, I would also consider `lme4` an option).

So far I managed to fit an `lme` model with only one within-subject factor, but not two (see below).

### What I tried

I can fit an `lme` model if I have just [one within-subject factor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/10909/442):

```
require(nlme)
 m1 <- lme(mean ~ condition*group*problem, random = ~1|code/problem, 
           data = d, subset = topic == "1")

anova(m1)
                        numDF denDF F-value p-value
(Intercept)                 1   531   12101  <.0001
condition                   2   177      31  <.0001
group                       1   177       2  0.2178
problem                     3   531      35  <.0001
condition:group             2   177       1  0.3672
condition:problem           6   531      24  <.0001
group:problem               3   531       1  0.2180
condition:group:problem     6   531       2  0.0281
```

This (especially the df) nicely correspond with the results from an standard ANOVA (using
`ez`):

```
require(ez)
ezANOVA(subset(d, topic == "1"), dv = .(mean), wid = .(code), between = .(condition, group), within = .(problem))$ANOVA

Warning: Data is unbalanced (unequal N per group). Make sure you specified a well-considered value for the type argument to ezANOVA().
                   Effect DFn DFd     F                             p p<.05     ges
2               condition   2 177 30.69 0.000000000003611248905859672     * 0.13079
3                   group   1 177  1.53 0.217821969825403999321267179       0.00374
5                 problem   3 531 34.85 0.000000000000000000014254103     * 0.10028
4         condition:group   2 177  1.01 0.367225806638525886782531416       0.00492
6       condition:problem   6 531 24.40 0.000000000000000000000000142     * 0.13503
7           group:problem   3 531  1.48 0.217959293081550348203379031       0.00472
8 condition:group:problem   6 531  2.38 0.028119961573665430004664856     * 0.01499
```

Trying to fit this data with two within-subject factors in `lme` fails (either per code, or per dfs):

```
m2 <- lme(mean ~ condition*group*problem*topic, random = ~1|code/(problem*topic), data = d)
# fails: Error in getGroups.data.frame(dataMix, groups) : 
#  Invalid formula for groups

m3 <- lme(mean ~ condition*group*problem*topic, random = ~1|code/problem/topic, data = d)
# the next model takes some time (probably already an indicator, that it is the wrong model)
# and produces wrong denominator df!

# with both factors as ANOVA
m4 <- ezANOVA(d, dv = .(mean), wid = .(code), between = .(condition, group), within = .(problem, topic))

#effects are the same
all(row.names(anova(m3))[-1] == m4$ANOVA$Effect)

#denominator dfs are not:
anova(m3)$denDF[-1] == m4$ANOVA$DFd

# only for effects with topic:
row.names(anova(m3))[-1][!(anova(m3)$denDF[-1] == m4$ANOVA$DFd)]
```

**UPDATE**: As the precise error or nesting is somewhat unclear I here provide the equivalent `aov` call (this is the "standard" model via `aov`), which matches the results from `ezANOVA`. The critical error term is `Error(code/(problem*topic))`:

```
m5 <- aov(mean ~ (condition*group*problem*topic) + Error(code/(problem*topic)), d)
summary(m5)
```

Comment: Hi there, could you describe more about how group, condition, topic, and problem are related to each other in the design?

Comment: Ohh, I am sorry I omitted this. It is a fully randomized experimental design. `group` and `condition` are two fully crossed between-subject factors (i.e., each cell consists of a unique set of participants). `topic` and `problem` are two fully crossed within-subject factors: Each participant responded to four different problems (denoted as `MP`, `MT`, ...) for each of the four different topics (1 to 4), in total each participant responded to 16 problems. The design is fully randomized (allocation to condition and order of topic and problems).

Comment: @Michelle see also my update.

Comment: Hi again, so `problem` is nested in `topic` and `group` and `condition` are not involved in any nesting?

Comment: @Michelle As far as I understand nested, I think `problem` and `topic` are both nested within `code` which is the variable identifying the participant. `group` and `condition` are not nested within `code`.

Comment: Are the p-values from `lme` actually reasonable? I don't know much about the topic, but `lme4` does several things different (like not giving p-values and not having a default `forecast` method) for what appear to be good reason.

Comment: @Wayne Totally. They are pretty much the same as the p-values from the ANOVA (which is the usual way to analyze this data in Psychology).

Comment: There is a function called pvals.fnc in the languageR package that allows you to get p values (calculated using Markov chain Monte Carlo sampling) for lme4 models. Perhaps you could try that?

Comment: Also, I'm more familiar with lme4's syntax than nlme, but does "random = ~1|code/problem/topic" mean you're trying to get random slopes for each subject for each of the within subjects variables? The model might be too complex. I would have just started with random intercepts for each subject.

Comment: @Marius - that's quite an involved hierarchy, so I agree with your comment about it being a complicated model.

Comment: @Marius See my updates and my answer about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my question on this thread: [Repeated measures ANOVA with lme in R for two within-subject factors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13784/442) (somehow this thread was already one of my favorites, I must have forgotten about it). The specification is a little unhandy.

```
m6 <- lme(mean ~ condition*group*problem*topic, 
   random = list(code=pdBlocked(list(~1, pdIdent(~problem-1), pdIdent(~topic-1)))), data = d)
anova(m6)
```

However, the denominator dfs are still wrong, as noted in the [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13784/442) and apparent in comparisons between the ANOVA and `lme` dfs.

```
data.frame(effect = rownames(anova(m6)), denDf= anova(m6)$denDF)

m4$ANOVA[,c("Effect", "DFd")]
```

As long as there are no other ideas, I think I will need to do the analysis in `lme4`, for which I wil need to post another question.

Comment: You should get the same results with `lme4` though, except with no dfs calculated at all.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for your answer. Perhaps you have the time to look at my follow-up question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23874/442